# Is there a way to split JTextField with substrings into a double?

Tags: java, swing, parsing, double, jtextfield

Is there a way you can split up a JTextField using substrings and return it has a double. The problem is i will recieve an input from the user i.e 3+x+5*7+y or 5*y-x/4 in a JTextField and this will be a String. But in order to use it in my calculation, i believe it must be splitted or parsed into a variable which is double.

I believe you can take the index of the text, and check for everytime an -, +, *, /, x or y appears, and set the substrings together, but i can not figure out how this can be done.

It will  avariable which is named `double i` and used in the following context:

```
public void solve(double y, double h, int j, double i){      
xArray = new double[j];
yArray = new double[j];
for(int dex = 0; dex < j; dex++){
    F1 = h*f(x,y,i);
    F2 = h*f(x+h/2,y+F1/2,i);
    F3 = h*f(x+h/2,y+F2/2,i);
    F4 = h*f(x+h,y+F3,i);

    y = y + 1.0/6.0*(F1+2*F2+2*F3+F4);

    xArray[dex] = x;
    yArray[dex] = y;

    x = x + h;
   }   
 } 
private double f(double x, double y, double i){
 return i; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried for splitting the string?  You could use a regex with split

Comment: By any chance you could give me an example of how you think it can be done using regex?

Comment: `str.split("[+\\-*/]")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate a math expression given in string form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/how-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 0):

> I believe you can take the index of the text, and check for every time an -, +, *, /, x or y appears and set the substrings together, but I can not figure out how this can be done.

this can be done with `KeyListener` interface which it provides 3 methods that can help you `keyPressed`, `keyReleased` and `keyTyped` each one of them has it's own functionality (although them names checks them out but their time of execution varies, a lot.)

here is an example

```
public class MyListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            //empty implemntation , we are not using it 
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            //here we are implementing what we want for the app
            //using the KeyEvent method getKeyChar() to get the key that activated the event.
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            //let's check it out !
            System.out.println(c);
            //now we got it we can do what we want 
            if (c == '+'
                    || c == '-'
                    || c == '*'
                    || c == '/') {
                // the rest is your's to handle as your app needs
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //empty implemntation , we are not using it 
        }

    }
```

so to get the key that the users hit we get it from the `KeyEvent` object.

when coming to the component part we add it like this

```
JTextComponent jtc = //create it whether it's text field , area , etc...
MyListener ml = new MyListener();
jtc.addKeyListener(ml);
```

the rest depends on how you are going to use the text `String` and remember this answer's how to know what the users just typed (char by char) but as an approach it's very bad !! imagine that the users decides to remove a digit or to change the caret location ,how would you handle it ??
so as our friend @phflack said I would recommend using `Regex` or `String.split`
something like this:-

```
String toSplit = "5-5*5+5";
        String regex = "(?=[-+*/()])";
        String[] splited = toSplit.split(regex);
        for (String s : splited) {
            System.out.print(s + ",");
        }
```

and the output of this

```
5,-5,*5,+5,
```

but this is hardly a `Regex` I just showed you a sample for more information about the `Regex` [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and for the `KeyListener` you can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) and I hope this solved your problem.